# Reverse LinkedList

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Following two codes has been given for reverse a linked list, the first one is working correctly but the second one is not. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Working Code:

```
def rev(curr, prev):
    if not curr:
        return prev
    next = curr.next
    curr.next = prev
    prev = curr
    curr = next
    return rev(curr, prev)
```

Not Working Code:

```
def rev(curr, prev):
    if not curr:
        return prev
    # next = curr.next
    curr.next = prev
    # prev = curr
    # curr = next
    return rev(curr.next,curr)
```

> I am calling both above function in this way :
>
> rev(head,None)

**Input :**

```
1->2->3->4->None
```

**First code's output :**

```
4->3->2->1->None
```

**Second code's output :**

```
1->None
```

**Desired output of the second code :**

```
4->3->2->1->None
```

Comment: What is the desired output of the second code? 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: 4->3->2->1->None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the recursive call `return rev(curr.next,curr)` after doing:

```
curr.next = prev
```

So in your initial call `rev(head, None)` you set `head.next = None` and then calling `rev` with `None` (and returning head).

Change to:

```py
def rev(curr, prev):
    if not curr:
        return prev
    next = curr.next
    curr.next = prev
    return rev(next,curr)
```